# How to mock getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive() response

Tags: spring-boot, soap-client, webservicetemplate

I'm consuming soap service in spring boot with spring soap client and writing unit test.

How can I mock `getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive()`

Tried almost everything but couldn’t get it to work.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: put the method which you are trying to test with the test which you have tried

Comment: @pvpkiran figured it out. ended up using MockWebServiceServer.